# Steering deadzone

Tags: controllers

I got a Logitech F310 controller from one of my friends recently. So I plugged it in and ran project cars.

The main problem I noticed right off the bat was the steering deadzone despite having it turned to zero in the game. I downloaded the Logitech software and the deadzone was set to zero but it was still there in game. I've also tried this other software called x360 with an anti deadzone option but I don't have the slightest clue about how to make it work.

Granted, the deadzone isn't very big and it's still drivable but fine adjustments are almost impossible to make.

I've seen several posts complaining about the same problem here and there but they are all old and some people claim that Logitech has fixed it.

**Tldr**;  Is it possible to completely eliminate steering deadzone on Logitech controllers?(if possible test project cars. F1 games are fine as well)
If not, can any of you guys still manage to drive reasonably good without too much twitching?

Comment: When you calibrate the device, does the display detect movement before you move away from the deadzone? It's possible there is a small mechanical deadzone that cannot be configured out (without opening the device up and looking)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by calibrate? It's not happening now but I don't think I've done much apart from just installing Logitech software

Comment: Also, should I shorten my question? I feel like I might have given too many unnecessary details.

Comment: Have a look in control panel, game controllers or devices and printers. If your wheel is listed there it should have a properties option, with a calibrate function within.

Comment: There's no calibrate option under properties. Ive looked it up and its not there where its supposed to be so i think its already been done. No, there is no movement before i move out of the deadzonne. The deadzone is showing in the test option though.

Comment: so you can see movement on the machine before the 'deadzone' is escaped. That does sound like a software issue. Try another program that uses the wheel and see if it does it in there.

Comment: Yeah I can see movement. Isn't that what a deadzone is? My question was how to remove it since it was still there despite setting to zero in software. Also, I have a Logitech controller not a wheel. Does anyone use a deadzone in sims btw?

Comment: The reason for the question was to investigate whether the issue was indeed software and thus fixable with settings, drivers or whatever, or whether the deadzone was hardware based, and only fixable with a modification to the hardware. Your answers have cleared that up as being software related.

Comment: So, what do I do? The default Logitech software doesn't seem to be doing much good. Maybe you could put a better one as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The thumbsticks, however, clearly have a deadzone of 2.4mm and an acceleration as soon as the F310 detects movement. As a result, characters or vehicles in a game can not be controlled as precisely.

Even the next model up sucks too.

> Because of its inferior vibration function, the dead zone in the thumbsticks and the unwieldy triggers, we find ourselves unable to recommend the Logitech F710.

You need to drop more than $30 if you want good thumbsticks.

> The **[Microsoft Xbox 360 Controller] thumbsticks do not have a dead zone** and operate in a very precise manner, offering you a great degree of precision when controlling a character or a vehicle.

Even with a 360 controller you still have to 'click' for fine adjustments - that's the down side of not having a dead zone. There are always tell tail sounds of someone playing a racing game with a 360 controller - the stick snapping back to zero every 1/8th of a second... which is where the intrinsic problem comes into play:

> We only noticed one flaw: the thumbsticks do not always properly reset to the central position, but sometimes keep transmitting the tiniest of movements.

Just be sure that you're not buying a MS knockoff. I love Logitech, but they should stick to making mice.

([source](https://us.hardware.info/reviews/5518/5/gamepads-review-7-models-for-pc-logitech-f310))

Comment: You're saying it's a physical deadzone right?Why is it there though? What's so hard in making a controller with no deadzone?

Comment: @Skawang - Without a deadzone your controller has to *reliably* return to zero *every* time, or it's junk anyway. It's a lot easier to make a piece of junk with crappy tolerances and a spring that *will* fail after only a million swivels. And as it begins to fail, you won't notice because it was crappy in the first place - because it has a giant deadzone.